# Apache server with Phusion Passenger not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a rails app that I am trying to start with apache. I get this error when I try to do so

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:395:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:277:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:400:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
Error ID
5e0368ce
Application root
/home/developer/sites/2performant/admin
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
development
Ruby interpreter command
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2performant-admin/wrappers/ruby
User and groups
uid=1000(developer) gid=1000(developer) groups=1000(developer),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),131(sambashare),999(vboxsf)
Environment variables
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
GEM_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2performant-admin
SHELL = /usr/bin/zsh
APACHE_RUN_USER = developer
IRBRC = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/.irbrc
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXdwOQcU
MY_RUBY_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3
USER = developer
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = development
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2performant-admin/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
WSGI_ENV = development
PWD = /home/developer/sites/2performant/admin
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = developer
LANG = C
NODE_PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/node_lib
NODE_ENV = development
SHLVL = 0
HOME = /home/developer
RAILS_ENV = development
LOGNAME = developer
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.14
GEM_PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2performant-admin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = development
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
RUBY_VERSION = ruby-2.2.3
Ulimits
Unknown
System metrics
------------- General -------------
Kernel version    : 3.19.0-59-generic
Uptime            : 1h 55m 6s
Load averages     : 0.71%, 0.57%, 0.36%
Fork rate         : unknown

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :    2
Average CPU usage :  21%  --   7% user,   0% nice,  14% system,  79% idle
  CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 2           :  43%  --  14% user,   0% nice,  29% system,  57% idle
I/O pressure      :   0%
  CPU 1           :   0%
  CPU 2           :   0%
Interference from other VMs:   0%
  CPU 1                    :   0%
  CPU 2                    :   0%

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :  11648 MB
RAM used          :   3015 MB (26%)
RAM free          :   8632 MB
Swap total        :  16381 MB
Swap used         :      0 MB (0%)
Swap free         :  16381 MB
Swap in           : unknown
Swap out          : unknown

General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 2.2.3
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.4.8
RubyGems paths = ["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2performant-admin", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global"]
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 2
MINOR = 2
TEENY = 0
PATCHLEVEL = 173
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-2.2.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorarchhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
sitearchhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-linux
vendorhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH = 
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3' '--disable-install-doc' '--enable-shared'
vendorarchdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
vendorlibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
vendordir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitearchdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
sitelibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0
sitedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby
rubyarchdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
rubylibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0
ruby_version = 2.2.0
sitearch = x86_64-linux
arch = x86_64-linux
sitearchincludedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/x86_64-linux
archincludedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include/x86_64-linux
sitearchlibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/x86_64-linux
archlibdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/x86_64-linux
libdirname = libdir
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3
RUBY_LIB_VERSION = 
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE = 3  /* full */
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/ri
rubysitearchprefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchprefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/x86_64-linux
MAKEFILES = Makefile GNUmakefile
PLATFORM_DIR = 
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
EXPORT_PREFIX = 
COMMON_HEADERS = 
COMMON_MACROS = 
COMMON_LIBS = 
MAINLIBS = 
ENABLE_SHARED = yes
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -lruby
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG = -Wl,-R/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -L/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib -lruby
LIBRUBY = libruby.so.2.2.0
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so.2.2 libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.2.2.0
LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
rubyw_install_name = 
EXTDLDFLAGS = 
EXTLDFLAGS = 
strict_warnflags = -std=iso9899:1999
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat
debugflags = -ggdb3
optflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math
cxxflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat
cflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat
cppflags = 
NULLCMD = :
DLNOBJ = dln.o
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
CAPITARGET = nodoc
RDOCTARGET = nodoc
DTRACE_REBUILD = 
DTRACE_OBJ = 
DTRACE_EXT = dmyh
EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
ARCHFILE = 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
RUNRUBY_COMMAND = $(MINIRUBY) $(srcdir)/tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext $(RUNRUBYOPT)
PREP = miniruby
BTESTRUBY = $(MINIRUBY)
CROSS_COMPILING = no
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
rubylibprefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby
setup = Setup
ENCSTATIC = 
EXTSTATIC = 
STRIP = strip -S -x
TRY_LINK = 
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG =  -Wl,-R%1$-s
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%1$-s
LINK_SO = 
ASMEXT = S
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 = 
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC = 
ARCH_FLAG = 
DLDFLAGS = 
ALLOCA = 
codesign = 
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
PYTHON = 
DOXYGEN = 
DOT = 
DTRACE = 
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
SET_MAKE = 
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP = 
WINDRES = 
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS = 
AS = as
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header = 
CC_VERSION = gcc -v
COUTFLAG = -o 
OUTFLAG = -o 
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
LD = ld
GCC = yes
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
GREP = /bin/grep
CPP = gcc -E
CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS =   
LDFLAGS = -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
CFLAGS =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  -fPIC
CXX = g++
CC = gcc
NACL_LIB_PATH = 
NACL_SDK_VARIANT = 
NACL_SDK_ROOT = 
NACL_TOOLCHAIN = 
target_os = linux
target_vendor = pc
target_cpu = x86_64
target = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
host_os = linux-gnu
host_vendor = pc
host_cpu = x86_64
host = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
RUBY_VERSION_NAME = ruby-2.2.0
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = pc
build_cpu = x86_64
build = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 2.2.3
HAVE_BASERUBY = yes
target_alias = 
host_alias = 
build_alias = 
LIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
ECHO_T = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C = 
DEFS = 
mandir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/man
localedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/locale
libdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib
psdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/doc/ruby
dvidir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/doc/ruby
htmldir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/doc/ruby
infodir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/info
docdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/include
localstatedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/var
sharedstatedir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/com
sysconfdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/etc
datadir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share
datarootdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/share
libexecdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/libexec
sbindir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/sbin
bindir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin
exec_prefix = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_STRING = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 
PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
PACKAGE_NAME = 
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/bash
archdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
topdir = /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
enumerator.so
rational.so
complex.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/unicode_normalize.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
thread.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/thread.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/errors.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/platform.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tmpdir.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.2.3-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/shellwords.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/union_station/connection.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/union_station/transaction.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/lock.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@2parale/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/union_station/core.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
```

In etc/apache2/sites-available I have this line which is ok(as I checked .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset):

`<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        RailsEnv development

 PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@2performant-admin/wrappers/ruby
    </IfModule>`

I did install bundler and all the gems. And also passenger start starts passenger instance.

I am happy to provide any more details necessary.

Does anyone have any idea why would I get this problem ?

Comment: are you using gemset ?

Comment: yes the passenger gem is also there

Comment: that passenger gem is present in your gemset ?

Comment: yes, it is in the gemfile, gemset and gemfile.lock

Comment: can you use `passenger-config --ruby-command # get the current ruby version with gemset.` Check this path is same as you mentioned with PassengerRuby. If not please update with the path given by above command.

Comment: sadly it is . I do have another application up and running with another gemset but same version something like ruby-2.2.3@2performant-main